# Generate data script from DbContext in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on entity framework and would want to generate and insert/update/delete script from the DbContext object, when changes are about to be saved. As of now I have only been able to get the DDL script from the context, by using the following snippet.

```
string str = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_objDataContext).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```

Is there a way to generate a script for all the changes?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any built-in way to generate DML scripts for changes before the `SaveChanges()` method is called, but it is possible to intercept insert/update/delete commands as they are being sent to the DB after `SaveChanges()` has been called.

EF 6 introduced two extensibility points for such scenarios.

It it possible to set the `_objDataContext.Database.Log` property a `TextWriter`, where all SQL commands issued by the context will be logged.

Another option is implementing an interceptor, that is called by the EF when it is about to execute a command or after the command has been executed. Interceptors allow you to log the SQL command being sent and even provide a way to suppress execution of the command.

To create an interceptor you need to write a class that implements the `IDbCommandInterceptor` interface and register this class in Entity Framework.

```
DbInterception.Add(new MyInterceptor());
```

For more details you can see a [sample implementation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx).

---

A solution for older versions of the Entty Framework might be a wrapping provider around your current db provider.

Comment: This is just the thing that i was searching for!
also something that might help others:

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
dbContext.Database.Log = s => sb.AppendLine(s);